# How can I perform IIS stress test 40,000 http requests per second?

Tags: iis, web-server, scaling, stress-testing

I'm the co-founder of a startup which is in the beginning and growing rapidly. I want to test an stress scenario on my IIS server to help figure out the resource needed from our cloud service, like 40,000 http request per second

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst I don't disagree with people who have one favourite tool, such as JMeter, or ApacheBench, the problem is, from a naïve point of view, you'll run this from one server, probably in the same Availability Zone as your server, and not get an entirely accurate load test.

Have a google about for Cloud-based load testing facilities, that way, they'll use lots of different servers, from all over the world, so you'd get a more accurate representation of when your site goes viral.

Comment: I googled: cloud based load testing, and the top hit looks like a very promising offering from Sendgrid.

Answer (score 3):

JMeter can be used for this.  I've not used it for web service testing myself, but I have used it to load-test a SQL mirror, as well as load-testing a Java application server.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html

Edit: I suppose, since I've used JMeter for load-testing a Java application server, that could be considered web service testing.